# unable to add or update records in servlet /jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to submit form with post method like :

```
<form action="/context/controller" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="add_record"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="u_name" /></td>                        
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Visible :</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"/> No
                    &nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1"/> Yes  
                </td>       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add record"/>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

and I'm getting form data in doPost() of controller servlet as :

```
String updateParam = request.getParameter("update");
System.out.println("Param value : " + updateParam); 
if (updateParam.equals("add_record")) {
        recordDAO = new RecordDAO();
        System.out.println("add if true Param value : " + updateParam);
        Record record = new Record();
        String name = request.getParameter("u_name");
        String visible = request.getParameter("visible");
        record.setName(name);
        subject.setVisible(visible);        
        recordDAO.addRecord(record);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }
```

this line

```
System.out.println("Param value : " + updateParam);
```

prints `Param value :  add_record` on the console but if condition never becomes true, thus I'm unable to add records, please tell me where is my bug which is preventing code of if condition from execution.

Comment: maybe you need to trim the String in updateParam
"test" and "test " for instance will not return true when an equals is called

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, so mark it as an answer, please. This may help others

Answer (score 0):

There is one whitespace before "add_record", that's why your condition never becomes `true`.

So modify your condition to `if (updateParam.equals(" add_record")) {` or, which I prefer, modify your parameter to output the string without whitespaces.